# appengine objectify text search

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, gae-search

Maybe I am missing something but is there any way to use the new text search features as described in the 2011 presentation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B7FyU9wW8Y (approx. 30min mark) with Objectify, Entities, and Java? I realize it is an experimental release but the text search features that are present don't seem to cover the full extent they discussed in the presentation. I don't want to have to write my own code to manage the creation, updates to documents. But I don't currently see another way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't use Full Text Search to search through entities in Datastore; you'll need to create search documents in a search index to use the Full Text Search API, as described [in these docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview).

Comment: Yes I know you need search documents but in the 2011 presentation they  talked about being able to annotate your entities to have that done for you. I don't see that in this release.

Comment: The current API doesn't support doing that; it's still in experimental and isn't feature-complete.